# Convert multiple columns to a single row based on Column 1 & 2 Values Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an excel sheet

```
A AAA 1
A AAA 2
A AAA 3
A ABC 1
A ABC 2
B AAA 1
B AAA 2
B AAA 3
B ABC 1
B ABC 2
```

I need it to look like

```
A AAA 1 2 3
A ABC 1 2
B AAA 1 2 3
B ABC 1 2
```

I have this code to convert

```
A 1 2 3
A 1
A 2
A 3
```

But can't find the reverse

```
Sub MakeOutput()

    Dim iInputRow As Long
    Dim iInputColumn As Long
    Dim iOutputRow As Long

    iOutputRow = 1 '- counter for which row to paste to
    '- loop through each row on the input sheet
    For iInputRow = 1 To Sheets("Input").Range("A" & Sheets("Input").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '- loop through each column inside of each row
        For iInputColumn = 2 To Sheets("Input").Cells(iInputRow, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
            Sheets("Output").Range("A" & iOutputRow).Value = Sheets("Input").Range("A" & iInputRow).Value
            Sheets("Output").Range("B" & iOutputRow).Value = Sheets("Input").Cells(iInputRow, iInputColumn).Value
            iOutputRow = iOutputRow + 1
        Next iInputColumn
    Next iInputRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will avoid writing to cells one at a time and uses an array to greatly speed up processing time:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim ACell As Range
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim sCurrent As String
    Dim sLine As String

    Set wsInput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Set wsOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

    With wsInput.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Sort .Resize(, 1), xlAscending, .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1), , xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
        ReDim arrResults(1 To .Cells.Count, 1 To 1)
        For Each ACell In .Resize(, 1).Cells
            If ACell.Value & "|" & ACell.Offset(, 1).Value <> sCurrent Then
                sCurrent = ACell.Value & "|" & ACell.Offset(, 1).Value
                ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = sCurrent
            End If
            arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) & "|" & ACell.Offset(, 2).Value
        Next ACell
    End With

    With wsOutput.Range("A1").Resize(ResultIndex)
        .Parent.UsedRange.Clear
        .Value = arrResults
        .TextToColumns .Cells, xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    End With

End Sub
```

I tested it using over 325,000 rows of data and the code completed in less than five seconds.

Comment: I ran it on a small group and it worked great, is there a line of code to say what line it is on?  Before I run it on the whole 190k?

Comment: I updated the code to accomodate for a small bug, then I tested it using over 325,000 rows of data and the code completed in less than five seconds.

Comment: HOLY **** that was fast, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. It is a bit of a mind twist :)

```
Sub CustomTranspose()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim num As Long
    Dim m As Long: m = 1
    For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ''The next line of code will show what line you are on 
        ''in the status bar at the bottom of the excel window
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing row " & i & " of " & Rows.Count

        num = 0
        For j = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & j).Value And Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & j).Value Then
                If i <> j Then
                    Range("D" & j).Value = "duplicate"
                End If
                num = num + 1
            End If
        Next j
        If Range("D" & i).Value <> "duplicate" Then
            Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A" & m)
            For k = 1 To num
                Sheet2.Cells(m, 3 + k - 1).Value = Range("C" & i + k - 1).Value
            Next k
            m = m + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ''This line clears the StatusBar
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Comment: this didn't gave the following output, here is the link to the original file and the output https://www.dropbox.com/s/um0mio3jwlk3bd3/Test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I thought you really had ones and twos in your data :). I have updated my answer. Please mark as answered if you are satisfied with it

Comment: This works great, I have 190,000 lines, can you add a line of code that says what line it is on?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking for

Comment: with 190,000 row I imagine this will run awhile, is there a line of code that can tell me where in the process it is.  I thought this would do it if I put it at the beginning and end of the procedure 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True